# response status change not working on connect for nodejs

Tags: node.js, response

On connect `res.status(400).send('wrong');` is not working. 
How can i make the status change for the response to 400?? Is there any other way to do it on connect.

Comment: You're trying to use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) code with Connect.

Comment: Suggestions: If you know your answer then you should not post question here :)

Comment: @abdulbarik Why? This is a Q&A site, this kind of activity is encouraged.

Comment: yes, @BenFortune you are right but if you can get answer within 2 mins mean you have answer and there are lot of question is there which matches the same

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer it should be like

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.end(JSON.stringify("not found"));
```

Comment: great answer, it worked for me. would like to know the source for your answer to learn more on this subject.